# Binding value to html check box not working

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to show check box checked if the the value is true and un checked if the value is false. Here is my Html

```
<label class="checkbox-inline nopaddingleft" for="radio1">
    <input name="radio1" type="checkbox" id="radio1" 
        class="checkbox-inline margin-right-five" value="name" 
        data-ng-checked="{{insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed}}" /> Scrub
</label>
```

I am trying to bind this  data-ng-checked="{{insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed}}" it will be true or false.Its not working can any one point out mistake i am doing thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using ng-checked, just use ng-model.

```
<input name="radio1" type="checkbox" id="radio1" 
    class="checkbox-inline margin-right-five" value="name" 
    data-ng-model="insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed" />
```

It will do all the checking for you. Check out the example in the docs for [Angular Checkbox](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.checkbox).

You can use `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` combined with `ng-model` to set your model (`isScrubbed`) to something other than true/false.

If you did want it to work with `ng-checked` I think you just remove the `{{}}` since it's an expression. But really, you're probably better off using ng-model.